# Infix to Postfix program doesn't work as intended

Tags: c, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

This is my attempt to write a program that can convert any expression in infix to postfix format. I assign -1 to the top to indicate the stack is empty. When push, the top is incremented, when pop, the top is decremented. However, when I type in `a+b`, the output only gives me `ab` without the `+` operator, while when I type `(a+b)`, it says *segmentation fault*. I reckon there's something wrong with my stack, but couldn't figure out what went wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE 30

typedef struct Stack
{
    int top;
    int capacity;
    char* storage;

} stack;

int isEmpty(stack* a);
char topelement(stack* a);
char pop(stack* a);
void push(stack* a,char b);
bool isOperand(char a);
int Precedence(char a);
stack* NewStack(char* a);
void InfixPostfix(char* a);

int main(void)
{
    char expression[SIZE];
    printf("Please enter an expression:");
    scanf("%s",expression);
    InfixPostfix(expression);
    printf("\n");

}

int isEmpty(stack* a)
{
    if(a->top==-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else
    return 0;
}

char topelement(stack* a)
{
    return a->storage[a->top];
}

char pop(stack* a)
{
    if(isEmpty(a)==1)
    {
        printf("Stack is Empty\n");
        return '$';
    }

    else
    return a->storage[a->top];
    --(a->top);


}

void push(stack* a,char b)
{
    ++(a->top);
    a->storage[a->top]=b;
}

bool isOperand(char a)
{
    if ( (a >= 'a' && a<= 'z') ||(a>='A' && a<='Z'))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else
    return 0;

}

int Precedence(char a)
{
    if(a=='+' || a=='-')
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if(a=='*' || a=='/')
    {
        return 2;
    }

    if(a=='^')
    {
        return 3;
    }

    else
    return -1;
}

stack* NewStack(char* a)
{
    stack* b= malloc(sizeof(stack));

    if(b!=NULL)
    {
        b->top=-1;
        b->storage=malloc((strlen(a))*sizeof(char));
        return b;
    }
    else
    return NULL;

}

void InfixPostfix(char* a)
{
    int i; int j=-1;

    stack* b=NewStack(a);

    if(b!=NULL)
    {

        for(i=0;  i<strlen(a) ;i++)
        {
            if(isOperand(a[i]))
            {
                a[++j]=a[i];
            }

            if(a[i]=='(')
            {
                push(b, a[i]);
            }

            if(a[i]==')')
            {
                while(isEmpty(b)==0 && topelement(b)!= '(')
                {
                    a[++j]= pop(b);
                }


            }

            else
            {
                while(isEmpty(b)==0 && Precedence(a[i]) <= Precedence(topelement(b)))
                {
                    a[++j]=pop(b);
                    push(b,a[i]);
                }
            }


        }

        while(isEmpty(b)==0)
        {
            a[++j]=pop(b);
        }

        a[++j]='\0';

        printf("%s",a);

    }


}
```

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `b->storage=malloc((strlen(a))*sizeof(char));` you seem to be missing to allocate one more `char` to hold the `0`-terminator.

Comment: b->storage=malloc((strlen(a)+1)*sizeof(char)); is this correct? I have tried this and it's still not working :(

Comment: Do not change the code after comments/answers have been given, as this renders them to be ununderstandable. Add updates. I rolled back you last change though.

Comment: It's still not working. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Plus how do I updates without modifying the original code?

Comment: Just add the new version to the end of you question.

Comment: This is the very moment you have a good reason to learn how to use a debugger. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the already suggested `malloc` correction, there are a few more to make.

- In `pop()` there's

  ```
      return a->storage[a->top];
      --(a->top);
  ```

  where the last code line isn't reached; change that to `return a->storage[a->top--];`
- In `InfixPostfix()`, `else` are missing before `if(a[i]=='(')` and `if(a[i]==')')`.
- In `InfixPostfix()`, after the loop

  ```
                  while(isEmpty(b)==0 && topelement(b)!= '(')
                  {
                      a[++j]= pop(b);
                  }
  ```

  a `pop(b);` is missing - the element `'('` must as well be removed from the stack.
- In `InfixPostfix()`, the `push(b,a[i]);` must be removed from the loop

  ```
                  while(isEmpty(b)==0 && Precedence(a[i]) <= Precedence(topelement(b)))
                  {
                      a[++j]=pop(b);
                      push(b,a[i]);
                  }
  ```

  and placed after that loop - the operator in `a[i]` has to be put onto the stack only once.